# How do I get started with a RESTful login in wildfly 9?

Tags: json, jax-rs, wildfly-9

I tried to do a simple login application [here on github](https://github.com/cosmingodeanu/jaxrs-json-wildfly) 
but when I try to see the json from the following url  http://localhost:8080/loginpoc/loginp/status I get a not found page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't review you're entire project, but there are a few things wrong. Firstly you're using Jersey which is not used by WildFly. You also have a dependency on RESTEasy which is the JAX-RS implementation used in WildFly, but you shouldn't need a dependency on it. It's provided by the container.

All of your dependencies should also be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Also you need a `@Path("/")` on your `Login.java`.

You're directory structure is also not a [standard maven directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) which is probably why your deployment does not fail as your WAR probably doesn't include any compiled Java classes. The `src/java` directory should be in `src/main/java`.

Finally if this is more than just an exercise in playing with JAX-RS I'd suggest looking at something like [Keycloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) for authentication.